# PHP multiple strings regex inside an "if" condition

Tags: php, regex

I wrote a regex in PHP. It tests if a string contains either one of the following strings: "...aft...", or "...fire...". The code works.

```
if( !( preg_match("/aft/i", $string1) || preg_match("/fire/i", $string1) ){
    $flag = false; 
}
```

My question is this: can this if condition be re-written more succintly, with just one preg_match(), instead of 2, which I have right now?

Comment: Yes use the pipe `|` that is a logical OR. But if these substrings are in a particular position in the url, you can eventually do something using `parse_url`. (As an aside: your question will be probably downvoted, closed, and deleted.)

Comment: Since you are looking for literal strings, you can also use `strpos`.

Comment: i made an edit, i don't need to parse url, it's just a string. don't worry if my question gets deleted because i don't care

Comment: Doesn't matter either way you don't know which one matched, whether it has both or just one. Either way you get less information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is probably the pipe operator

```
...preg_match("/(aft|fire)/i",$_GET['ua']) ...
```

By the way, i find this tool very helpful when buildings regular expressions, it also provides some examples: https://regexr.com/

Comment: there is no benefit to using capture groups for this task.  Please help SO to reduces its new redundant content by flagging/voting to close duplicate questions instead of answering.